# Rendering Two JSON Items In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, reactjs

This seems like a duplicate question but the answers on the others posts don't seem to work for my issue here.

I'm needing to render two JSON items here within my index method in my controller:

```
 def index
    @user = User.all
    @libraries = Library.all.order(:created_at)

    user_cards = current_user.libraries

    render :json => @libraries, :include => :user
    render :json => user_cards
  end
```

I attempted to do it this way (failed with a 500 error):

`render :json => @libraries, user_cards, :include => :user`

And I also attempted to do it this way (also failed with a 500 error): `render :json => @libraries :include => [:user, :user_cards]`

**UPDATE**

This is the most recent attempt as rendering the json properly:

```
def index
    @user = User.all
    @libraries = Library.all.order(:created_at)

    user_cards = current_user.libraries

    render json: {
      user_cards: user_cards,
      libraries: @libraries.as_json(include: [:user])
    }
  end
```

The issue with this is that I am now getting an error on `libraries` throughout my application as it stands. If I simply just render json like I originally had it (`render :json => @libraries, :include => :user`), I do not get this error. So, I'm assuming the way I have it is still not correct. The exact error on `libraries` is being called within one of my React components where I use filter:

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.librarys.filter is not a function`

Error Location:

```
let filteredCards = this.props.librarys.filter(
        (library) => {
          return library.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || library.desc.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        }
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller can only return one response, you can achieve this with combining this two returns into one:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json  { render json: { user_cards: user_cards,
                                libraries: @libraries } }
end
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help! How would I still use the `:include => :user` with that format?

Comment: try this: `libraries: @libraries.to_json(include: [:user] )`

Comment: Thanks again for your help. It's actually giving me `noMethodError` on `respond_to`. The includes and everything else seems to be fine, just weird how it's giving me that error on that.

Comment: are you using rails in api mode? there is no respond_to method there. Try without `respond_to do |format|`, just `render json: ...`

Comment: Thanks for your continued help! Removing the `respond_to` did help as I am using rails in api mode. I don't think it's currently working even though I'm no longer getting the 500 error. I'll update my original post.